# Linux Multiprocessings in kernel space

Tags: linux-kernel, multiprocessing

I do multiprocessing in user space by creating multiple threads and pinning them to specific cpu cores. They process data in a specific place in memory, which is never swapped and it is constantly filled with new data by a streaming device driver. I want to get the best in term of speed so I thought to move everything in kernel space to get rid of all the memory pointer conversion and the kernel->user communications and vice versa. The process will be started with an ioctl to the driver. Then multiple threads will be spawned and pinned to specific cores. The process is terminated with another ioctl by the user.

So far I gathered info about kthreads, which is not so well documented, and I wrote this in the ioctl function:

```
thread_ch1 = kthread_create(&Channel1_thread,(void *)buffer,"Channel1_thread");
thread_ch2 = kthread_create(&Channel2_thread,(void *)buffer,"Channel2_thread");
thread_ch3 = kthread_create(&Channel3_thread,(void *)buffer,"Channel3_thread");
thread_ch4 = kthread_create(&Channel4_thread,(void *)buffer,"Channel4_thread");
printk(KERN_WARNING "trd1: %p, trd2: %p, trd3: %p, trd4: %p\n",thread_ch1,thread_ch2,thread_ch3,thread_ch4);
      
kthread_bind(thread_ch1,0);
kthread_bind(thread_ch2,1);
kthread_bind(thread_ch3,2);
kthread_bind(thread_ch4,3);
     
wake_up_process(thread_ch1);
wake_up_process(thread_ch2);
wake_up_process(thread_ch3);
wake_up_process(thread_ch4);
```

and the ioctl returns.
Each Channeln_thread is just a for loop:

```
int Channel1_thread(void *buffer)
{
    uint64_t i;
    for(i=0;i<10000000000;i++);
    return 0;
}
```

The threads seem to never be executed and thread_ch1-4 have non NULL pointers. If I add a small delay before ioctl returns and I can see the threads running.

Can someone shine some light?

Thanks

Comment: What memory pointer conversion are you talking about ?

Comment: Pointer dereferencing. As I understood in kernel space you go directly to the IOMMU.

Comment: And how is it different from user-mode?